Arduino IDE fails to program LilyGo T-Display ESP32 device
Is it possible to reprogram a ESP32 board with 2.0.17 board driver, if it has been programmed with 3.0.7?  It seems to only be compatible with 3.0.7 now, like the boot loader is not able to go back to 2.0.17.  Is that supposed to be the case, or is there something I can do to downgrade to be compatible with 2.0.17?  I tried hitting the EN / Reset combo to get the board ready, but that didn't work.
Background:
I'm using Arduino IDE 2.3.4.  The board is a LilyGO T-Display.  I have a sketch that compiles fine, but fails to program now.  The same sketch was able to program before, but now won't.  The error I get is "Upload error: Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 2".
The project that I'm working on has 2 ESP32 devices talking to each other over ESP_NOW to run a mecanum wheel robot.  The code was developed a year ago, and wouldn't compile.  The problems stemmed from the esp32 board package being at rev 3.0.7.  I updated the controller code to work, and was able to get it to compile and download to the board.  The car code also would not compile, and when I tried to update it to work, only 1 wheel would turn.  I narrowed the problem down to the pwm code being used, LED Control (lecd).  I decided to downgrade the esp32 board package back to 2.0.17, and the car code would compile and all the wheels worked.
I had a couple changes to make to the controller, and I ran into the problem of not being able to download the code.  I upgraded the board package esp32 by Espressif Systems back to 3.0.7, and could build and download the code again.

See the documentation for board management, under section "Changing version".
